# Document is [my_spreadsheet_id] missing (perhaps it was deleted?)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Occasionally (actually it's happening quite often) I'm getting a "Document tIbdnvK2ZBY_7SQ2skESDvg is missing (perhaps it was deleted?)" error which obviously isn't true. Can anyone please put some light to this issue? Maybe some good solution to it?

Comment: Looks like there is a script running under a trigger when this error is shown. If so, under whose id is the script run ? Does the user (under whose id the script runs) have access to the spreadsheet in question ?

Comment: I'm the owner and the only editor of the spreadsheet. And yes, I'm getting this error after triggering the script.

Comment: The solution for the problem is same as here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293856/script-execution-time-varies-every-time-i-run-it). Apps script cannot handle more than ~250 cells in one go (i.e. when performing getRange or setComments). Anyone knows if it's going to be improved in the future?

Comment: I get that error when opening my spreadsheet, not when processing rows. My script has been running every 15 minutes, unchanged, for a few weeks and hasn't had this error before. This is the second intermittent error I get from Apps Script API calls. I think Apps Script just isn't ready for prime time yet. :/

Answer (score 1):

I have a few scripts working on timers and occasionally get this error, it seems to happen when the sheet the script tries to access is too busy calculating or dealing with other requests (the old Google sheets would go offline sometimes hich caused this too).

It happens much less with the new Google sheets, and reducing the frequency is good too if possible- I moved to the form submit trigger then an hourly on top in case the first trigger fails.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use SpreadsheetApp not DocumentApp to open sheet.