# Script execution time varies every time I run it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Each time I run my script, it's execution times is significantly different from the previous run. The script is performing some custom validation on a ~500 rows sample sheet. The execution time varies from 7s to 300s. Interesting fact here is that this 300s is more than 5min (which I believe is the official limit, yes?).

Could anyone try to help me understanding this behaviour? 
Thanks in advance, 
Łukasz

Answer (score 0):

5 minutes NO, Your script will time out at 6 minutes.

Can you post the code? so I can better understand what your trying to achieve.

Are the different execution times your getting, always varied, when running your script on the same sample sheet, containing identical data? 
Or do the execution times only vary when the sample sheets data is different?

Are the custom validations your script is performing, changing each time you run your script?

Comment: The code is quite complex (around 500 lines) so I rather not paste it here. I can add that I'm doing not more than 10 calls per script run to various services (MailApp, ServiceDB, SpreadsheedApp and CacheService) and the script is being fired by time-based trigger. The sample data is always the same (the script is still in development phase). I'm trying to make it faster, but the more I try the more I believe it's not possible unless Google App Scripts improve?

Comment: Here is a link to some analysis tools that might be helpful https://developers.google.com/speed/

Comment: Have you considered adding relevant libraries to your project, and making calls client side rather than server side? if this is possible for your project.

Comment: Bubz: how would I do that? And about what libraries you're talking?

Comment: After some testing it turned out that the different execution time is only when doing setBackgroundColors or/and setComments for a big number of cells (>500). When I lowered it to 200-250, execution time stabilized. It would be really nice to by able process bigger number in one go though...

Comment: Im no expert, (just teaching myself, in spare time). You should be calling data to an array/arrays, then processing tests and checks etc in the array/arrays, then dumping results/changes back to data sources from the array/arrays. If your not already doing this, it should speed up execution times markedly.