# Google Script:DocumentApp.openById() showing document is missing error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was trying to access google sheet by following method

```
  var baseDoc = DocumentApp.openById(docIDs[0]);
```

The script is associated with the same file which is being accessed. But it is showing following error

> 'Document is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read
>   access?)'

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

Need to replace DocumentApp with SpreadsheetApp.
DocumentApp opens Google docs (analogue of MS Word).
SpreadsheetApp opens Google Spreadsheets (analogue of MS Excel).
So your code will be:

```
var baseDoc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(docIDs[0]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You may refer with this thread: ["(perhaps it was deleted?)" Spreadsheet Error in Google Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23918661/perhaps-it-was-deleted-spreadsheet-error-in-google-scripts).

> If you've deployed your script to run "as the user accessing the app" the spreadsheet must be shared with such user, so that a script running as him can access it. If you have a "general" audience, you'll have to share this spreadsheet with "anyone with the link can view". Unless of course you can change the deployment option to execute the app as you, the developer.
>
> Note that this does not necessarily expose your spreadsheet, because you don't have to handle your users the link, the script code (which can be private only to you) access it on their behalf, and since your code runs from a Google server the spreadsheet link is never leaked.

Also from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293141/document-is-my-spreadsheet-id-missing-perhaps-it-was-deleted), it might also occur when the sheet the script tries to access is too busy calculating or dealing with other requests..